# Copy and paste to blank row based on data in column

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts

I have a bit of experience writing VBA macros (but by no means an exprt), and am now starting to work with Excel 365 files exclusively online.  So I am trying to convert some VBA logic to Office Scripts.

I need a very simple script that performs the following:

Copy cells from A2:U2
Paste to the next blank row, based on data in column D

I've been dabbling with GPT to get help, but spinning in circles there.   I've run through at least half a dozen different scripts, and all of them have had various errors.  Following is the latest I have.

The error occurs with the getRange function.  I assume it is related to me 'destinationRange' variable.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    
    // Find the last used row in column D
    const lastRow = selectedSheet.getRange("D:D").getUsedRange().getLastRow();
    
    // Paste to range A8 on selectedSheet from range A2:U2 on selectedSheet
    const destinationRange = selectedSheet.getRangeByIndexes(lastRow.row + 1, 1, 1, 21); // 21 columns from A to U
    selectedSheet.getRange(destinationRange).copyFrom(selectedSheet.getRange("A2:U2"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `getLastCell()` gets the last cell in col D
- `getRangeEdge(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.up)` is equivalent to `End(xlUp)` in VBA
- `lastCellD.getOffsetRange(1,0)` gets the first blank cell

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [getLastCell()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.range?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&view=office-scripts#excelscript-excelscript-range-getlastcell-member(1))

> [getRangeEdge(direction, activeCell)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.range?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&view=office-scripts#excelscript-excelscript-range-getrangeedge-member(1))

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Find the last used row in column D
    const lastCellD = selectedSheet.getRange("D:D").getLastCell().getRangeEdge(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.up);
    // For testing, validate the last cell location
    console.log(lastCellD.getAddress())
    // Paste to first blank cell in col D from range A2:U2 on selectedSheet
    lastCellD.getOffsetRange(1,0).copyFrom(selectedSheet.getRange("A2:U2"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
}
```